# python no such element: unable to locate element {"method": "id","selector":"email"}

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

having trouble with my python code. I keep getting python no such element: unable to locate element {"method": "id","selector":"email"}

my code:

```
self.driver.get(redirecturl)

email = "testmail02015@
Password = "Passw0rd123"
emailFieldID = "email"
passwordFieldID = "password"
loginButtonXpath = "//button[@value='btnLogin']"

self.driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldID).send_keys(email)
self.driver.find_element_by_id(passwordFieldID).send_keys(Password)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath).click()
```

Comment: that means just that. there is no element with that id on your page.

Comment: can't really help you without the source of the page

Comment: Do you want to login into Gmail??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur no paypal.

Comment: <div class="fieldWrapper">
<label class="fieldLabel" for="email">Email</label>
<input id="email" class="hasHelp validate validateEmpty " type="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" value="" aria-required="true" required="required" name="login_email">

Comment: <div class="fieldWrapper">
<label class="fieldLabel" for="password">Password</label>
<input id="password" class="hasHelp validateEmpty " type="password" placeholder="Password" value="" aria-required="true" required="required" name="login_password">

Comment: <div class="actions">
<button id="btnLogin" class="button actionContinue" value="Login" name="btnLogin" type="submit">Log In</button>

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld ^^^ added elements

Comment: Wait for the elements to load and click... Selenium is way faster than you think...

Answer (score 3):

Usually the problem is that `find_element` runs too quickly before page fully loaded. So try to wait for elements to appear (in the example it waits for maximum of 10 seconds; less if element appears earlier):

```
...
emailFieldID = "email"
...

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_id(emailFieldID)))

self.driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldID).send_keys(email)
```

After that you can use `find_element` as usual.

Comment: what part of the script do i add this too? sorry

Comment: `WebDriverWait.until()` returns the element waited for. You can just capture that and `.send_keys()` to it. There's no need to scrape the page again.

Comment: @JeffC was trying to emphasize that waiting for `emailFieldID` was an arbitrary choice, nothing to do with the fact that the same field is operated upon.

Comment: What should I import to use this line?